# What is the name of this instrument that sounds like a pedal steel guitar?

Tags: guitar, piano, instruments

What is the name of this instrument?

Here [video](https://youtu.be/UDDBiKVbUd8?t=41) I'm thinking that the sounds produced by that instrument are similar to the sounds of a pedal steel guitar, because when I see the newer versions of the ghost riders in the sky, there is a similar sound produced by a pedal steel guitar. Like this:

[image]

It does look like a piano to me, but it has a shape like stairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound you hear coming from the gentleman's playing the keyboard-like instrument at [the 0:40 minute mark of the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDDBiKVbUd8&t=40s) is **not** the steel guitar sound, but a flute-like sound of a C major chord (2nd inversion, to root, to 1st inversion, and to 2nd inversion again an octave higher).

The instrument looks like it's a [Hammond B3 Organ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammond_organ#Console_organs), produced between 1954-1974, thus fits the release date of Neil LeVang's "Ghost Riders in the Sky" (1961).  You can hear a demo of this vintage organ [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVLhU7wcLUY), which has a similar sound to what you hear, controlled by the white and black drawbars just next to the top keyboard.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cmhpUk3t1o) introduces a keyboard player to the sound produced by various settings of the buttons and drawbars typical of a Hammond Organ, as well as samples of typical usage of a Hammond Organ.

Starting 2016, the Hammond Organ company sells the [XK-5](https://hammondorganco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/XK5-main-product.pdf) series that reproduces the B-3 sound digitally *and more*, with a similar look and feel as the B-3 (see the XK5 Heritage Pro System option in the [product brochure](https://hammondorganco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/XK5-main-product.pdf)).

Comment: If you read the vtcs, you'll appreciate that by providing answers to questions such as this, it will only encourage others to bombard the site with similar, unacceptable ones.

Comment: @Tim I agree with you in principle.  Still figuring out what Q's are acceptable here.  Unfortunately, at my reputation level I don't see any VTCs and there are no comments about the OP either.

Comment: @Tim (and GratefulDisciple): Some relevant meta threads are https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2443/78419, https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2941/78419, https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3307/78419, https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/722/78419, https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3415/78419 . Several parts of those, especially Doktor Mayhem on the first link, suggest that questions like the present one should be *on* topic.

Comment: Problematically, the phrase "instrument identification" can also mean "What makes the sound I hear at 0:30 in this song" and "Here's a guitar I got from my uncle; what brand is it?" For both of those there's no interest in handling. While "What the hell is an ondes martenot," aside from being googlable, would be more welcome. The present question has some hallmarks of both—a "what is this sound at this timestamp in this video" aspect, which would seem to make it very narrow in usefulness—but, especially in this answer, that organological (heh) aspect.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thank you for educating me more about what kind of questions are acceptable for this site.  BTW, it would be great if you nominate yourself for the election :-).  I'll vote for you!

Comment: Thanks! But I'm afraid I have the same problem as Richard; I enjoy contributing, but at least *shouldn't* spend as much time here as a mod ought!